# css files loaded from a different domain over ssl not working in MSIE 9 and below

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser, ssl-certificate

I am Serving static content from a different domain, I load my js and css files from a statc domain. But I faced a problem in pages using ssl, Although I load my css and js there through

"//static-domain.com/test.css"

so it automatically loads the css and js through ssl but in MSIE9 and below on ssl pages the page seems to be blocking the load of css and javascript.

Any solutions for this issue would be welcome

Comment: I have read that in IE 7 and 8 the protocol relative url causes the browser to double download css/js. I know this isn't the exact behavior you are noticing but maybe this is related?

Comment: I have just put together a quick test of this and not been able to reproduce the same behavior using MSIE 7, 8 or 9. I am wondering whether perhaps the issue is that the content is not available via https on the static domain in question?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out but it works perfectly fine on firefox and chrome also msie 10 only on msie 9 and below these files are blocked and I get a security warning if I allow the content in the warning then everything works fine

Comment: Oh you get a warning? you should include that in your question. Is it the mixed content warning?

Comment: Internet Explorer has blocked the website from displaying content with security certificate errors

Comment: is static-domain using a self signed ssl cert?

Comment: Sorry, still no dice, I accessed that via MSIE 9.0.8112.16421, no certificate error, loaded the css fine. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: thanks the issue is resolved it was an issue with the certificate

Comment: Can you please answer to your own question to close this and provide more details about the certificate issue?